# Como "contornar" uma palavra no input sempre que apertar a tecla espaço do teclado

Tags: jquery, input

É como a pergunta já diz, quero "contornar" uma palavra sempre que der um espaço, como nos exemplos a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não quero nada de auto-complete, quero apenas que quando der o "espaço" a palavra se contorne. Porem não tenho a minima noção de como fazer isso.

Comment: Já existem plugin para o Jquery q fazem exatamente isso.
Vou ver se encontro ele e te mando

Comment: Um plugin interessante é o [Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se fores ver o HTML gerado por esse input podes ver isto:

```
<div class="tag-editor" style="width: 666px; height: 26px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1; position: relative;">
    <span>
        <span class="post-tag">tag_a
            <span class="delete-tag" title="remover esta tag"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="post-tag">tag_b
            <span class="delete-tag" title="remover esta tag"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" tabindex="103" style="width: 536px;" /><span></span>
</div>
```

Ou seja, tens uma `div class="tag-editor"` que dentro tem um input. Cada vez que se prssiona `space` é gerado um `span` com o texto que está escrito **e** um outro `span` dentro do primeiro com o simbolo `x` para permitir remoção.

O código para fazer o que pedes é, usando o HTML em cima:

```js
$(".tag-editor input").on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        e.preventDefault(); // para prevenir criar um espaço
        var tag = this.value;
        if (!tag) return;   // no caso de não haver nada escrito ainda
        $(this).before('<span>' + tag + '<span class="remover">x</span></span>');
        this.value = '';    // limpar o input para nova tag
    }
});

$(".tag-editor").on('click', '.remover', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().remove(); // remover a tag clicada
});
```

```css
.tag-editor {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.tag-editor > span {
    background-color: #ccf;
    padding: 0 2px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.tag-editor span span { /* para o "x" que remove a tag */
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: #88b;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.tag-editor input { /* para remover aspeto tipico de input */
    border: none !important;
}

.tag-editor input:focus { /* para remover aspeto tipico de input */
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag-editor">
    <input type="text" tabindex="103" style="width: 536px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom, só uma dica "comentários" em css devem ser usados assim `/* comentário */`, por que em alguns casos isto ocasiona problema em alguns navegadores. +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento haha, obrigado. Bem sei mas estava distraído. Ainda não me habituei a este snippet do SO :)